# Grabbing text data from html to a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, text, numbers, each

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/Wa4pA/4

what seems to be valid code in my eyes doesn't work. I used a similar method earlier in the code and it worked fine, now my variable isn't affected. I'm grabbing text values from html and summing them up into a variable. I'm looking for a hint on why this doesn't work, and not a full working code.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var char_fr = 0;
    var char_cl = 0;
    var char_lr = 0;
    var char_pr = 0;
    $(".ares .value").each( function(){
        char_cr += Number($(this.text()));
        char_fr += Number($(this.text()));
        char_lr += Number($(this.text()));
        char_pr += Number($(this.text()));
    });
    $(".cr .value").each( function() {
        char_cr += Number($(this.text()));
    });
    $(".fr .value").each( function(){
        char_fr += Number($(this.text()));
    });
    $(".lr .value").each( function(){
        char_lr += Number($(this.text()));
    });
    $(".pr .value").each( function(){
        char_pr += Number($(this.text()));
    });
    $("#mainstats .fr .stat").text(char_fr);
    $("#mainstats .cr .stat").text(char_cr);
    $("#mainstats .lr .stat").text(char_lr);
    $("#mainstats .pr .stat").text(char_pr);
});
```

Again I'm looking for a lead on why it doesn't work, instead of a full code. At the same time, I'll be having a lot more variables with matching classes, would there be a smarter way to code this, rather than having a full block for each variable? The variables and classes are similar, but it would be just fine if they were an exact match, or maybe by "prefix_"+variable.

Thanks!

Comment: what _is_ happening instead?  Can you give sample output of what is vs. what should be happening?  This would be a great use for a JSFiddle, fyi.  But i think the issue is that you should be using html() or val() instead fo text, depending on the element

Comment: Is there any error logged into firebug

Comment: are you checking for errors?  char_cr is not defined, and where do any of these class names (.ares, .value) come from in yuir markrp?

Comment: corrected JSFiddle sorry http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/Wa4pA/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a jQuery wrapped DOM elements, use: `char_cr += Number($(this).text());` Your version is: `$(this.text())`

Comment: That was it, thank you! Just back from doing some actionscript :( Could explain it, I guess? :p